# Test whether an object is a DOM event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

From within a function like:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
  // ...
}
```

is there a reliable and efficient way to determine whether `e` is a DOM event?

Comment: How is `eventHandler` being called?

Comment: @TravisJ that isn't really relevant is it? The question is how can we test whether or not `e` is a DOM event.

Comment: @Shmiddty - I see, I think I had misunderstood the question.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js) is some interesting code that simulates events and uses jQuery. Perhaps you could use the list of properties and functions that it adds to the simulated events and check for those (or some of those). If its got enough of those functions and properties, you could consider it an event. (Sort of the "If it quacks like a duck, it is a duck" method of detection.)

Comment: Trevor, is your goal to prevent event spoofing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a reliable way to determine if a given object is **NOT** a DOM event.

1. `typeof e` will always return `'object'` for genuine Event objects, which is not helpful.
2. Any property that you might check for on the object can exist in both a genuine Event object or any non-Event object.
3. You might think that the prototype chain could be of use in determining this, but it has the same problem as #2 (can easily be replicated).
4. The `contructor` property might seem promising, but one could do this:

```
function DummyEvent(){
    this.constructor.toString = function(){
        return "function MouseEvent() { [native code] }";
    }
}
```

This ends up making `console.log(e.constructor)` print `"function MouseEvent() { [native code] }"`

So, is there a "reliable" way to tell if an object is an event? **No**.

**Edit** — Note that all of this is irrelevant if you want to prevent event spoofing as you can create real events easily.

```
var evt = new Event('click');
var evt2 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt2.initMouseEvent('click', ...);
//etc
```

**Edit2** — I've created a test [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5nvP/5/) trying to find some way to distinguish objects, but I haven't found anything definite yet. Note that I didn't bother to specify properties on the `DummyEvent` because those can obviously easily be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if the event bubbles `event.bubbles` up through the DOM it's DOM event.
But even if that statement is true its propagation might be stopped.

**UPDATED** :

OK the property you are looking for is `e.target` and for IE `e.srcElement`.
Both properties return the HTML element the event took place on which defines it as
DOM event.

However perhaps you should specify what you interpret as DOM event.
Do you mean browser's native events, because this is DOM event too:

```
var zoo = jQuery('#zoo');
zoo.bind('moo');
zoo.trigger('moo');
```

It is binded to a DOM node

Comment: `var spoof = { target: someDOMNode, srcElement: someDOMNode };` is not an Event object.

Comment: Then the function isn't an event handler either

Comment: A function is a function. You can call a function from anywhere (where it is in scope).

Comment: Where are you going, telling me that native functionality in js can be overridden or simulated , indeed that can be. Event object is an object after all from a native constructor.

Answer (score -1):

In jquery I created a testing function, something like this:

```
function isEvent(e) {
    try { 
        e.PreventDefault();
        return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
```

}

and testing code:

```
var o = new Object();
var e = $.Event('click');
alert(isEvent(o));
alert(isEvent(e));
```

the former alert shows false, while the latter shows true. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh6W7/2).

UPDATE: It's safer to call something like preventDefault instead of trigger.

Comment: If you assign type, this test fails: `e.type = 'click';` http://jsfiddle.net/eh6W7/1/

Comment: Same problem... just add a `PreventDefault` method to the object and you won't get a reference error.

Comment: ur right, so there is no way to verify is by checking the object events and methods.